# Configurar URL amigavel do CodeIgniter, em servidor windows

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou tendo o seguinte problema, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em CI, e essa aplicação ira ficar em um servidor windows. gostaria de saber como faria url amigável nesse tipo de servidor, pois já vi em alguns lugares, que não funciona o .htaccess.

Alguém teria alguma soluções ou uma dica que pudesse dar?

Comment: Depende, por exemplo no servidor IIS você consegue pegar a configuração do .htaccess e utilizar sem problemas só precisa instalar o `urlrewriter` para configurar sua aplicação, então depende onde vai utilizar se poderia ser mais especifico.

Comment: Virgilio, a pessoa que é encarregada do servidor, resolveu mudar hj, para um servidor linux. Muito obrigado pela ajuda e atenção a minha pegunta.